# AWS Terraform cloudwatch - Dashboard body reading from a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following body for my AWS_CloudWatch_Resource on terraform:

```json
 dashboard_body = jsonencode(
 dashboard_body = jsonencode(
{ 
    "widgets": [
        {
            "type": "metric",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 9,
            "height": 6,
            "properties": {
                "view": "bar",
                "stacked": false,
                "metrics": [
                    [ "AWS/AutoScaling", "GroupDesiredCapacity", "AutoScalingGroupName", "Momo-Test-ASG1" ],
                    [ ".", "GroupMaxSize", ".", "." ],
                    [ ".", "GroupTotalCapacity", ".", "." ],
                    [ ".", "GroupTotalInstances", ".", "." ],
                    [ ".", "GroupInServiceInstances", ".", "." ]
                ],
                "region": "eu-central-1",
                "title": "ASG1 statistics"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "metric",
            "x": 9,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 9,
            "height": 6,
            "properties": {
                "view": "bar",
                "stacked": false,
                "metrics": [
                    [ "AWS/AutoScaling", "GroupDesiredCapacity", "AutoScalingGroupName", "Momo-Test-ASG2" ],
                    [ ".", "GroupMaxSize", ".", "." ],
                    [ ".", "GroupTotalCapacity", ".", "." ],
                    [ ".", "GroupTotalInstances", ".", "." ],
                    [ ".", "GroupInServiceInstances", ".", "." ]
                ],
                "region": "eu-central-1",
                "period": 300,
                "title": "ASG2 statistics"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "explorer",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 6,
            "width": 24,
            "height": 15,
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    {
                        "metricName": "CPUUtilization",
                        "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
                        "stat": "Average"
                    },
                    {
                        "metricName": "NetworkIn",
                        "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
                        "stat": "Average"
                    },
                    {
                        "metricName": "DiskReadOps",
                        "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
                        "stat": "Average"
                    },
                    {
                        "metricName": "DiskWriteOps",
                        "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
                        "stat": "Average"
                    },
                    {
                        "metricName": "NetworkOut",
                        "resourceType": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
                        "stat": "Average"
                    }
                ],
                "aggregateBy": {
                    "key": "*",
                    "func": "AVG"
                },
                "labels": [
                    {
                        "key": "aws:autoscaling:groupName",
                        "value": "Momo-Test-ASG1"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "aws:autoscaling:groupName",
                        "value": "Momo-Test-ASG2"
                    }
                ],
                "widgetOptions": {
                    "legend": {
                        "position": "bottom"
                    },
                    "view": "timeSeries",
                    "stacked": false,
                    "rowsPerPage": 40,
                    "widgetsPerRow": 3
                },
                "period": 300,
                "splitBy": "",
                "title": "Average ASG1 and ASG2"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "metric",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 21,
            "width": 6,
            "height": 6,
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [ { "expression": "AVG(METRICS())", "label": "Average", "id": "e1" } ],
                    [ "CWAgent", "mem_used_percent", "InstanceId", "i-0f67225a5c04aebf9", "AutoScalingGroupName", "Momo-Test-ASG2", "ImageId", "ami-0502e817a62226e03", "InstanceType", "t2.micro", { "yAxis": "left", "id": "m1" } ],
                    [ "...", "i-00198c860886391f4", ".", "Momo-Test-ASG1", ".", ".", ".", ".", { "id": "m2" } ]
                ],
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "stacked": false,
                "region": "eu-central-1",
                "period": 300,
                "stat": "Average",
                "title": "mem_used_percent"
            }
        }
    ]
}
  )
}
```

As you can see, I am having the same widget for my `Momo-Test-ASG1` ( first Autoscaling group ) and `Momo-Test-ASG2` ( second Autenter code here scaling group ).

If I would have many ASGs to test, It would be problematic to hardcode the same thing for a lot of groups.
Is there any solution to make terraform read the ASGs from a list? instead of having to reproduce the same parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HashiCorp Terraform 0.12 Preview: For and For-Each](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each)

Using `for`

```
locals {
  asg_names = [
    "Momo-Test-ASG1",
    "Momo-Test-ASG2",
  ]
}

locals {
  body = [for asg_name in local.asg_names :
        {
            type: "metric",
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 9,
            height: 6,
            properties: {
                view: "bar",
                stacked: false,
                metrics: [
                    [ "AWS/AutoScaling", "GroupDesiredCapacity", "AutoScalingGroupName", asg_name ],
                    [ ".", "GroupMaxSize", ".", "." ],
                    [ ".", "GroupTotalCapacity", ".", "." ],
                    [ ".", "GroupTotalInstances", ".", "." ],
                    [ ".", "GroupInServiceInstances", ".", "." ]
                ]
                region: "eu-central-1",
                title: asg_name
            }
        }
        ]
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {
  dashboard_name = "my-dashboard"

  dashboard_body = jsonencode({ 
  widgets: concat(local.body, [{
      type: "text",
      x: 0,
      y: 7,
      width: 3,
      height: 3,
      properties: {
        markdown: "Hello world"
      }
    }])
  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but when I try to add a new widget after the written expression,  like this : 
,
        {
            "type": "explorer",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 6,
            "width": 24,
            "height": 15,
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
I get the error: Extra Characters after loop expression, do you know how I could add new widgets without getting this error ? thank you so much in advance.

Comment: @Nidorino94 I there was an extra space between `:`  and  loop. syntax  `for index, asg_name in local.asg_names:`. Updated

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. When trying to add a new widget, by separating the first widget with for loop , like for XXXXX {type:metric.......}, {type:explorer .....} then I always get the same problem.
In your initial response, you wrote more widgets ... how could you implement them ? Could you add an example please of at least another widget working with the mentioned one ?
Thanks

Comment: @Nidorino94 updated working code with a snapshot of the dashboard.

Comment: I understand, but my question is: how to separate two or more widgets, while using the for loop ? 
I mean, you are only using one widget, but with two it is a little bit problematic ?
can you add another widget to the code above ?
Thanks in advance ! your help was so precious !

Comment: @Nidorino94 added, it is just a matter of producing the structure which is needed, you should checkout `terraform functions`. The original idea remains the same, iterating the over the list.

Comment: quite interesting. Thank you so much !

Comment: @Nidorino94 it is upto you if you want to have separate `locals` even, I created just for clarity, you can omit that and have the block right in the resource section.